# Getting ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\nitrathod\Desktop\Angular\node_modules' in Angular 11 project

Tags: angular, node-modules

When I am trying to run the angular app below error is displayed.

> An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\nitrathod\Desktop\Angular\node_modules'
> See "C:\Users\NITRAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-kzNmoN\angular-errors.log" for further details.

[image: Error message screenshot]

Tried npm install to resolve this issue.

[after npm install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4WLP.png)

Project structure for more clarity.
[Project sturcture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDiEI.png)

Answer (score 18):

check your angular.json.

I had this problem

```
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
      "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
    ],
```

Should have been

```
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
      "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
    ],
```

This caused it to look for node_modules in the wrong place

Comment: I had same kind of issue after have upgrading to angular 13. It was looking for `@angular` at the root of my project instead of in `node_modules` folder. I had to correct the path of the material theme in the `angular.json` which was `"@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"`. I fixed it by using `"./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"`.

Comment: agreed, I have faced the same issue, always make sure the path of whatever is written inside Style[] in angular.json

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to run `npm install` to install all the required dependencies.

**EDIT:**
Looking at your screenshots, It seems that for some reason, your application is looking for the `node_modules` directory at the wrong place when you run `ng serve`:

It should be in `C:\Users\nitrathod\Desktop\Angular\outlook\node_modules`,
yet your application is looking into `C:\Users\nitrathod\Desktop\Angular\node_modules`, which is a wrong place.

Comment: Already tried this solution but still getting the same issue.

Comment: Also make sure you are running both of the commands in the right directory - make sure you are inside root project folder.

Comment: Yes I am running the command in the root directory only.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your project structure (i.e where everything is)? This might be useful.

Comment: I have added to the project structure in description.

Comment: How to fix the node_module issue? I tried to create the application in another folder still, the same issue is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just run: `ng uninstall @angular/materialn` to remove angular material theme from my project and then deleted               "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" from angular.json file. It solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. In my case it was directory permissions issue . I cloned using visual studio git plugin. It was solved once i cloned from git command line in another folder and executed git install there